# Constructor Expression in TypedQuery with CriteriaQuery

Tags: jpql

I was using JPQL NamedQueries earlier in order to get some values from one db-table A and put it into PartsOfA via a constructor expression like this: SELECT new ...PartsOfA(a.member) from A a where ...

Now I am trying to do the same with a TypedQuery which shall be created by using a CriteriaQuery.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

Example:

**TransferObject:**

```
public class BasicTeacherInfo {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public BasicTeacherInfo(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

}
```

**Query**

```
CriteriaQuery<BasicTeacherInfo> query = cb.createQuery(BasicTeacherInfo.class);
Root<Teacher> teacher = query.from(Teacher.class);
        query.multiselect(teacher.get("firstName"),teacher.get("lastName"));

List<BasicTeacherInfo> results = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();

for (BasicTeacherInfo info : results) {
    System.out.println("First name = " + info.getFirstName() + " "
        + "Last Name = " + info.getLastName());
}
```

*examples from http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/04/27/multiselect-criteria-api/*

By the way: You seem to misuse *TypedQuery* word. A Criteria Query is not a TypedQuery. `TypedQuery<T>` is the Type of e.g. a named query.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Merci! I did it just now.